# Four digits from 0 - 9 are entered and generate a new combination of four (4) digits,

Tags: python

To see how you can help me, for a class I need to create a program in Python, which four digits from 0 - 9 are entered and generate a new combination of four (4) digits,

Example:

The number I enter,

1348

Based on that number I entered, the program create a new combination of number and add 1 only to their first number,  2348.

Then, generate a second number and add 1 only to the second digit, 1448.

Then generate third number and add 1 only to the third digit, 1358.

Then generate a fourth number and add 1 only to the fourth number m, 1349.

The program must only accept numbers and not more than four digits.

This is the code I created:

```
print """
-------------------------------------------------------
|                           Number Generator                                |
-------------------------------------------------------
"""
print 
winnum = raw_input("Enter last wining 4 numbers separated from 0 to 9 by spaces: ")
items = winnum.split()
lst2 = [eval(x) for x in items]
print 
print
print"1 number this week: ", lst2[0]+1,lst2[1],lst2[2],lst2[3]
print
print"2 number to play this week: ",lst2[0],lst2[1]+1,lst2[2],lst2[3]
print
print"3 number to play this week: ",lst2[0],lst2[1],lst2[2]+1,lst2[3]
print
print"4 number to play this week: ",lst2[0],lst2[1],lst2[2],lst2[3]+1 
print
```

Comment: "but I Think is that's wrong" Well, what do your tests say?

Comment: Need to see actual output vs expected output.

Comment: `eval(x)`? Eww... use `int(x)` instead.

Comment: @timgeb sorry, I think I expressed myself wrong, the code I created generates the number with the sum, but if the number is 9 then it returns the number 10. There can not be number 10.

Comment: @JacobIRR Actual output: if I enter a number 9 the code output 10. Expected output:  The number I enter,  1348  Based on that number, the program create a new combination of number and add 1 to their first number,  2348. Then generate a second number and add 1 only to the second digit 1448. Then generate third number and add 1 only to the third digit 1358. Then generate  number and add 1 only to the third digit 1358. Then generate a fourth number and add 1 only to the fourth number 1349.

Comment: @HughBothwell I'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You skipped the part about "if the result when adding is greater than 9, return 0".

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    # Python 2.x
    inp = raw_input
else:
    # Python 3.x
    inp = input

def next_digit(i):
    return (i + 1) % 10

def main():
    prompt = "Please enter 4 digits separated by spaces: "
    a, b, c, d = [int(i) for i in inp(prompt).split()]

    print("Combo 1: {} {} {} {}".format(next_digit(a), b, c, d))
    print("Combo 2: {} {} {} {}".format(a, next_digit(b), c, d))
    print("Combo 3: {} {} {} {}".format(a, b, next_digit(c), d))
    print("Combo 4: {} {} {} {}".format(a, b, c, next_digit(d)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```